# SSAS - Cube browsing currencies displayed in USD format

Tags: ssas

I have built a cube using SSAS and whenever I browse the cube using Visual Studio or Excel the currencies are always displayed in USD format and not in the preferred GBP format.

I have checked the Login settings are in British English format but to no avail can I change the default currency format.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the language directly on your cube. In the Cube Designer, select your cube and modify the "Language" property.

Answer (score 0):

you have a LANGUAGE property on the dimension.  By default, the value of the LANGUAGE cell property of the cube is 1033, just set it to English (UK)

> You can explicitly specify the LANGUAGE cell property on objects such
>   as dimensions or cubes. If you do not specify the LANGUAGE cell
>   property on an object, the LANGUAGE cell property is inherited from
>   the parent of the object.
>
> If you do not specify the LANGUAGE cell property on a cube, the
>   LANGUAGE cell property of the cube is inherited from the database that
>   contains the cube. If you do not specify the LANGUAGE cell property on
>   the database, the LANGUAGE cell property is inherited from the server
>   object.